# What is the correct way to bind an event to a dynamically created button using jQuery in RoR?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

I've included a click event in my application.js file:

```
  $('#test_container').on( 'click', '#test_button', function(event){
    alert("HI");
    event.preventDefault();
  });
```

I'm dynamically creating that button via a partial in my application. The event never happens.  I thought jQuery's `on` works for even dynamically created things.  Is there something I am missing here?

I know about `live` and I believe it works but its depreciated so I am trying not to use it.

Comment: You need to preventDefault at first, then alert.

Comment: Is `#test_button` a descendant of `#test_container`? Is `#test_container` available when that code runs?

Comment: That makes no difference, since there's no parallel execution and no race conditions.

Comment: Yep, #test_button is a descendant of #test_container. #test_container is available in the initial page load. I never change #test_container.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Woah sorry about the `.live()`

then you used your `.on()` wrong.

```
$(document).on("click", '#test_button', function(){ 
  alert("Goodbye!"); 
});
```

The page for `.live()` shows how to convert to `.on()`:

http://api.jquery.com/live/

Comment: I'm avoiding the use of `live` because it is depreciated.

Comment: Is it ok to attach it to the `document`?  Would that hurt performance?